# AngularJS directive needs to watch two properties

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm making a game in Angular. Each player object has an `x` and a `y` property. Whenever the player moves, I want to start a timer that cycles through a couple background positions in the  sprite sheet.

I thought I would do this with a directive. The problem is that directives normally only let you set one expression to watch:

```
// "test" directive
module.directive("test", function() {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch(attrs.test, function(value) {
      // do something when it changes
    })
  }
})

// my template
<div test="name"/>
```

The nice thing about this approach, is the `test` directive doesn't have to assume the scope has any particular property. You're telling it what to use when you use the directive.

The problem is that in my case I need to kick something off if either x OR y changes. How can I do this?

```
<div test="player.x, player.y"/>
<div test="player.x" test-two="player.y"/>
```

Is there a best way to do this that you can think of? Basically I want to make a directive that does something on a timer if any of several properties change.

Comment: Note that I do know you can pass a function into scope.$watch, and return something custom, but this question is more about how I TELL the directive what to do in the function when I bind it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The easiest and most readable solution in my opinion is to use two attributes and simply set up two watches:

```
// "test" directive
module.directive("test", function() {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    var doStuff = function() {
      console.log(attrs.test);
      console.log(attrs.testTwo);
    }
    scope.$watch(attrs.test, doStuff);
    scope.$watch(attrs.testTwo, doStuff);

  }
})

// my template
<div test test="player1.x" test-two="player1.y" />
```

Comment: I like this syntax the best too, but what if I wanted to make it so this directive could be used on things that don't have an x or a y? All it does is activate when one or more properties change, but the user gets to decide?

Comment: How would you see the user specifying which attributes to watch?

Comment: I guess that's what I'm asking. How would you do what you recommend without forcing to ONLY work with x and y. With any two properties? or a single property, if the user wanted instead? See my comment on eventOn's answer.

Comment: there's now `watchGroup` you can squash the watches together `scope.$watch([attrs.test, attrs.testTwo], doStuff);`

Answer (score 7):

I would try to use a function in the $watch function.

Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/o3cnXm)

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', [])
.directive('myDir',function(){
  return {
    restrict:'E',
    template:'<span>X:{{x}}, Y:{{y}}</span>',
    link:function(scope, elm, attrs){
      scope.$watch(function (){
        var location = {};
        location.x = attrs.x;
        location.y = attrs.y;
        return location;
      }, function (newVal,oldVal,scope){
        console.log('change !');
        scope.x = newVal.x;
        scope.y = newVal.y;
      }, true);
    }
  };
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

});





 <div>X: <input type='text' ng-model='x'/></div>
  <div>Y: <input type='text' ng-model='y'/></div>
  <my-dir x='{{x}}' y='{{y}}'></my-dir>
```

Comment: Why store location inside the first param function of $watch?

Comment: then you can monitor the location object.

Comment: This is the way to use one watch to monitor more than 1 variable. I didn't say it is faster. However, I think it did save you one watch. You might gain some benefit from that. BTW, this is how the creators of AngularJS do it, I saw one core member use this way somewhere.

Comment: IF you are going to do this then why bother storing the variable... 

     scope.$watch(function (){
       return { x: attrs.x, y: attrs.y};
     }, ..., true);

Apart from this, you are now relying on deep equality.  I would still go with two watches that call the same function on a change.

Comment: well, I think it is the same. Location is a local variable. You just make it anonymous. What do you mean by "deep equality" ?

Comment: The true at the end of the call to $watch is telling AngularJS to use angular.equals rather than === to test whether the value is the same as before.

Comment: From doc, that means compare object for equality rather than for reference. Since I use object here, I need to compare value not reference. if you use watch twice, you don't need to set it true, because it not an object.

Comment: There's no issue with storing location, if it makes it more readable. The variable itself will die every time the function is resolved. It's a non-issue. However, having an extra $watch, is far more intensive.

Answer (score 1):

There is some work arounds for this

[Watch multiple $scope attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11952579/watch-multiple-things-in-angularjs)

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/angular/yInmKjlrjzI

Comment: What about `<div test="{{player.x}} {{player.y}}"/>`? The problem is you have to jump over and use `attrs.$observe` instead of `scope.$watch`. It seems weird to have to change which function I use depending on how it's used

Answer (score 1):

```
scope.$watch(function () {
  return [attrs.test, attrs.test-two];
}, function(value) {
      // do something when it changes
}, true);
```

see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19436487/observe-multiple-attributes-at-the-same-time-and-fire-callback-only-once)

you can also use **$watchGroup** - see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11952579/watch-multiple-scope-attributes)