# AngularJS interpolated attrs $observe

Tags: angularjs, directive

How to bind scope from attrs.$observe?

```
<test func="hohoho"></test>
app.directive('test', function(){
    return {
         restrict: 'E'
        , scope: { parentFunc: '@func'}
        , link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                var func = '';

                attrs.$observe('func', function(val) {
                    func = val;
                    console.log(func);
                })
                console.log('end');
                console.log(func);
                            console.log(scope.parentFunc);

                });
        }
    };
});
```

when i run, it will print

```
end
undefined
undefined

(an empty string)
hohoho
```

why i get undefined when i print func and parentFunc?

Comment: The directive also runs before values I bound, I suspect

Comment: hi liviu, thx for comment, but i need to get value observe outside the observe, how to get value? http://jsfiddle.net/Jx4hm/1/

Comment: completed now, thx anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe those `undefined` lines are being printed somewhere else on the code and not on the Directive.

Check this fiddle and look at the console output: http://jsfiddle.net/bmleite/Jx4hm/

You should get something like this (which is the expected output):

> end
>   1
>   2 undefined
>   3 hohoho

Comment: hi bmleite, i have update fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Jx4hm/1/ How i bind value func to set value for scope.func2 outside the observe? thx anyway

Comment: I don't know if I understood it correctly, but please check if this fiddle helps: http://jsfiddle.net/bmleite/Jx4hm/2/

Comment: thanks for help, i use $watch to multiple value http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11952579/watch-multiple-things-in-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

> How i bind value func to set value for scope.func2 outside the observe?

From the [Directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) page, under section "Attributes":

> during the linking phase the interpolation hasn't been evaluated yet and so the value is at this time set to undefined.

Only in the $observe callback function will the value contain the interpolated value.  You'll have to move the code that is "outside the observe" into the $observe callback function.

Or try @bmleite's Jx4hm/2 fiddle, where '=' is used instead of '@'.  If you don't need interpolatation (e.g., you don't need to do something like func="Hello {{modelInstance}}"), you can use '=', which sets up two-way databinding, but the value is available in the linking function.  ('@' sets up one-way databinding.)

Comment: ok thanks for your info, i use $watch to multiple value http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11952579/watch-multiple-things-in-angularjs