# How to $watch multiple variables?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I do have two `$scope` variables. They are called `$scope.image` and `$scope.titleimage`.

Basically the store the same type of contents. I want to track now when either one of them gets updated. But so far I could not figure out how to have two variables tracked in a single `$scope.$watch()` callback.

```
// How can I watch titleimage here as well?
$scope.$watch('image', function(media) {
    console.log('Media change discoverd!');
});
```

Comment: You can create a new object on your scope that has these two properties and then watch the parent object. Such as `$scope.o={image: scope.image, titleImage: scope.titleImage};`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I combine watching of multiple fields into one watch with AngularJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17872919/can-i-combine-watching-of-multiple-fields-into-one-watch-with-angularjs) --- please see **dluz**'s answer and see the **last example** of how to do that by `watchCollection`.

Comment: actually, I've just found even better one: `watchGroup` see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11952579/watch-multiple-scope-attributes-in-angularjs

Answer (score 32):

`$watch` method accepts a function as first parameter (beside a string). 
`$watch` will "observe" the return value of the function and call the $watch listener if return value is changed.

```js
$scope.$watch(
  function(scope){
    return {image: scope.image, titleImage: scope.titleImage};
  }, 
  function(images, oldImages) {
    if(oldImages.image !== images.image){
      console.log('Image changed');
    }
    if(oldImages.titleImage !== images.titleImage){
      console.log('titleImage changed');
    }
  }, 
  true
);
```

Also you might observe a concatenated value, but that doesn't let you know which one of the observed values actually changed:

```js
$scope.$watch('image + titleImage',
  function(newVal, oldVal) {
    console.log('One of the images have changed');
  }
);
```

And you can also watch an array of scope variables:

```js
$scope.$watch('[image, titleImage]',
  function(images, oldImages) {
    if(oldImages[0] !== images[0]){
      console.log('Image changed');
    }
    if(oldImages[1] !== oldImages[1]){
      console.log('titleImage changed');
    }
  },
  true
);
```

Comment: Don't you mean `oldImages.titleImage !== images.titleImage`? (You have `oldImages` twice.)

Comment: The first approach of returning an object is the best! clean and simple

Comment: I almost didn't see the little true parameter in the bottom on your first example. That makes the comparison between old and new objects a deep comparison. Worked fine after adding that :)

Comment: @Trojan I edited, but not yet reflecting...waiting for peer review

Answer (score 16):

Stewie's suggestions will work. But there are a thousand ways to skin this cat. I'd submit that if you're watching two separate values, there's nothing wrong with setting up two watches for them with a shared function between them:

### functional programming to the rescue!

Using functions to create functions is awesome.

```js
function logChange(expr) {
   return function(newVal, oldVal) {
      console.log(expr+ ' has changed from ' + oldVal + ' to ' + newVal);
   };
}

$scope.$watch('image', logChange('image'));
$scope.$watch('titleImage', logChange('titleImage'));
```

---

#### OR... you could even wrap the watch setup in it's own function (much less exciting, IMO):

```
function logChanges(expr) {
   $scope.$watch(expr, function(newVal, oldVal) {
      console.log(expr+ ' has changed from ' + oldVal + ' to ' + newVal);
   });
};

logChanges('image');
logChanges('titleImage');
```

.. but I have a thousand of them, you say?

```
//assuming the second function above
angular.forEach(['image', 'titleimage', 'hockeypuck', 'kitchensink'], logChanges);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use computed and return multiple variables in an array that you want to listen to that should execute the same function.

```
computed: {
  photo () {
    return [this.image, this.title]
  }
},
watch: {
  photo () {
    console.log('changed')
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer was found here:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watchCollection

"for arrays, this implies watching the array items; for object maps, this implies watching the properties"

Example:

```
$scope.$watchCollection(function () {
    return {t : ctrl.time, d : ctrl.date};
}, function(value) {
    ctrl.updateDateTime();
});
```