# Can I combine watching of multiple fields into one watch with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way in AngularJS to combine this into the one $watch or do I still need a $watch for each thing I watch?

```
    $scope.$watch('option.selectedContentType', function () {
        $scope.getData();
    });

    $scope.$watch('option.selectedContentStatus', function () {
        $scope.getData();
    });
```

Answer (score 44):

You can find below some variations on how to use $watchCollection

http://jsbin.com/IYofiPi/4 - [working example here](http://jsbin.com/IYofiPi/4).

Check your console.log to see the event being fired.

**Watching items of an Array**

```
$scope.cities = ['Salvador', 'London', 'Zurich', 'Rio de Janeiro']; //Array

$scope.$watchCollection('cities', function(newValues, oldValues) {
  console.log('*** Watched has been fired. ***');
  console.log('New Names :', newValues);
});
```

**Watching properties of an Object**

```
$scope.city = {
  name: 'London',
  country: 'England',
  population: 8.174
}

$scope.$watchCollection('city', function(newValues, oldValues) {
  console.log('*** Watched has been fired. ***');
  console.log('New Names :', newValues);
});
```

**Watching a list of scopes variables ($scope.firstPlanet, $scope.secondPlanet)**

```
$scope.firstPlanet = 'Earth';
$scope.secondPlanet = 'Mars';

$scope.$watchCollection('[firstPlanet, secondPlanet]', function(newValues){
  console.log('*** Watched has been fired. ***');
  console.log('New Planets :', newValues[0], newValues[1]);
});
```

> Starting from AngularJS 1.3 there's a new method called [$watchGroup](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watchGroup) for observing a set of expressions.

Comment: +1: the last fragment is what the OP asked for. Cool trick, seems to work.

Comment: btw. there's also watchGroup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11952579/watch-multiple-scope-attributes-in-angularjs

Comment: Cool! good to know @quetzalcoatl! I will also update my answer here. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

If you use angular 1.1.4, you can use [$watchCollection](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.4/docs/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24watchCollection), here is the code snippet from the sample code in the documentation.

```
$scope.names = ['igor', 'matias', 'misko', 'james'];

$scope.$watchCollection('names', function(newNames, oldNames) {
  $scope.dataCount = newNames.length;
});
```

Comment: -1: This is not what the OP asked for. Your snippet watches the '$scope.names' for changes. Please review the question carefully. He wanted to "pack up" multiple similar watches into one watch expression. <b>dluz</b>'s last fragment (watching a list of scope variables) is the closest thing, because it's one expression that would 'watch' two scope variables.