# Is there a way I can combine multiple AngularJS watches?

Tags: angularjs

I have this:

```
        $scope.$watch('option.sCreatedBy', function (newValue, oldValue) {
            if (newValue && newValue !== oldValue) {
                _u.oyc.put('sCreatedBy', newValue);
                $scope.grid.data = null;
            }
        });

        $scope.$watch('option.sModifiedBy', function (newValue, oldValue) {
            if (newValue && newValue !== oldValue) {
                _u.oyc.put('sModifiedBy', newValue);
                $scope.grid.data = null;
            }
        });
```

Functionality is the same for all of these plus a few more than I don't show above.

Is there a way I could combine these watches into one watch and watch / modify multiple things at once ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I combine watching of multiple fields into one watch with AngularJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17872919/can-i-combine-watching-of-multiple-fields-into-one-watch-with-angularjs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now, you're creating two identical, anonymous functions, then passing them to each `$watch` method. The second argument is just a callback function, so you might as well just name the callback function and pass the reference.

```
var watchCallback = function (newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue && newValue !== oldValue) {
        _u.oyc.put('sCreatedBy', newValue);
        $scope.grid.data = null;
    };
};
$scope.$watch('option.sCreatedBy', watchCallback);
$scope.$watch('option.sModifiedBy', watchCallback);
```

Another, and perhaps more Angular-ish approach would be to use `$watchCollection` instead of `$watch`:

```
$scope.$watchCollection('[option.sCreatedBy, option.sModifiedBy]', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue && newValue !== oldValue) {
        _u.oyc.put('sCreatedBy', newValue);
        $scope.grid.data = null;
    };
});
```

It's important to note that the first argument to `$watchCollection` isn't an array, but instead a string *looking* like an array.

Comment: $watchCollection looks good but How can I know which value is changed. Your answer has this: _u.oyc.put('sCreatedBy', newValue); but what if the sModified by is the thing that triggers the watch? Thanks