# Angular.js binding one property to another

Tags: javascript, angularjs

As a contrived example, let's say I have an angular controller that looks something like this:

```
function OverflowController($scope) {

  // initialize the count variable
  $scope.count = 0;

  // pretend the overflow logic is complex and doesn't belong in a filter or view
  var count = parseInt($scope.count);

  if (count < 100) {
    $scope.overflow = "normal";
  }
  else if (count < 200) {
    $scope.overflow = "warning";
  }
  else {
    $scope.overflow = "error";
  }

};
```

and I have a view that looks like this:

```
<input ng-model="count">
<p>Count: {{count}}</p>
<p>Overflow? {{overflow}}</p>
```

How can I bind the overflow property of the scope to the count property in such a way that when the count is updated, the overflow automatically gets updated too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use $watch: ([http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$watch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch))

```
function OverflowController($scope) {

  // initialize the count variable
  $scope.count = 0;

  $scope.$watch('count', function (count) {
     // pretend the overflow logic is complex and doesn't belong in a filter or view

     if (count < 100) {
       $scope.overflow = "normal";
     }
     else if (count < 200) {
       $scope.overflow = "warning";
     }
     else {
       $scope.overflow = "error";
     }
   });
};
```

Comment: Is the view automatically updated? How does Angular know the function passed to `$watch` has updated the `overflow` property?

Comment: view is updated automatically.   After a watch function runs angular does a digest which checks all of your template values for changes.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to watch it for changes:

```
  $scope.$watch('count', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    if (!angular.equals(newVal, oldVal)) {
       updateCount();
    }
  });

  function updateCount() {
    var count = parseInt($scope.count);

    if (count < 100) {
      $scope.overflow = "normal";
    }
    else if (count < 200) {
      $scope.overflow = "warning";
    }
    else {
      $scope.overflow = "error";
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

just use getOverflow as $scope function:

```
<div ng-controller="OverflowController">
<input ng-model="count" />
<p>Count: {{count}}</p>
<p>Overflow? {{getOverflow()}}</p>
```

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller("OverflowController", function ($scope) {
    // initialize the count variable
    $scope.count = 0;   
    $scope.getOverflow = function () {
         var count = parseInt($scope.count);
        var overflow = "error";
        if (count < 100) {
           overflow = "normal";
        } else if (count < 200) {
            overflow = "warning";
        }
        return overflow;
    }
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/alfrescian/Gt9QE/

Comment: The only issue with doing it this way is that your getOverflow function will be run everytime angular does a digest, which is often.  Using a $watch means it will only be run when count changes.

Comment: yub, but you doesn't have to add a 2nd watch if an additional property has to be considered  to calculate overflow

Comment: You can just add the property to the same watch.  Check out my answer on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11952579/watch-multiple-scope-attributes-in-angularjs