# Angular Select: build string

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to build a url where parts of the url string are dynamic build with a select box.

The watch is only called at startup:

```
$scope.$watch('url', function () {
    $scope.buildUrl();
}, true);
```

Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/mkeuschn/wJGFm/

best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$watch` will only fire if the value being watched changes.  In this case, it is better to watch `dimension`, since this is the selection that is changing.  Then, you can re-assign the `dimension` part of the url and re-build.

Here is an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GW8HJ/).

**JS:**

```
$scope.buildUrl = function () {
    $scope.url.dimension = $scope.dimension.value;
    $scope.completeUrl = $scope.url.base + "dateFrom=" + $scope.url.from + "&dateTo=" + $scope.url.to + "&dimension=" + $scope.url.dimension;
};

$scope.$watch('dimension', function () {
    $scope.buildUrl();
}, true);
```

Comment: So I have to watch from, to and dimension separately (I want to use datepicker for the other fields)?

Comment: @Marko You can watch multiple scope variables [like this answer shows](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23495281/269608).