# Call Angular-function upon $scope-variable change

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and trying to set up a function that gets called upon whenever a variable is changed.

Currently I have a dropdown-menu, with ng-model bound to a $scope.userRating. And I am trying to get a function that gets called immediately when the user changes the value using the dropdown.

I have been looking at $watch, but not quite sure on how to get it to work. I also tried to make a ng-click function on the  in the html, but ng-clicks don't seem to trigger.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use $watch .
Example-

```
 $scope.$watch('modalVarible',function(newVal,oldVal){
//do your code
}
```

Here on the change of variable 'modalVarible' this watch will be called.

Comment: I tried doing that Anita. Just a quick


 $scope.$watch((userRating), function(newvalue, oldvalue){
    console.log(userRating);
})



However, it seems to only be called when I visit the partial, and not when changing the variable :/

Comment: Then what error it gives ? And it should be $scope.$watch('userRating',.. without brackets

Comment: That worked! Thanks, apparently it was just the formatting of what I had in the paranthesis. Thank you Anita!

Answer (score 0):

we can use `$watchGroup` in `controller of our directive` to bind $scope variable changes (bidirectional)

```
$scope.$watchGroup(['var1','var2'],function () {

});
```

you can also check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11952579/watch-multiple-scope-attributes).