# AngularJS - call listener of directive on click and pass data to it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

So, I was working with directives in AngularJS. What I want to achieve is that call the listener of the directive on the click of a button and pass it some data from the controller.

#### Here's my directive (example)

```
app.directive('graphVisualization', function() {
    var containerid = document.getElementById('left-graph-container');
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
          data: '=',
          val: '=',
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('data', function(newVal, oldVal) {
                //listener code
            })
        }
    }
```

#### Here's my HTML

```
<div graph-visualization data="graphdata" val="stability">
</div>
<div>
    <input type="button" value="Call" ng-click="setData(6)" />
</div>
```

#### And here's my controller

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function() {
    $scope.graphdata = ['time1', 'time2', 'time3'];
    $scope.setData() = function(val) {
        $scope.data = val;
        //now call the directive's listener code i.e. 'link' function and pass it '$scope.data'
    }
}])
```

So, I need to pass `$scope.data` from the controller to the directive and then run the code of the `link` function using that data. What I'm doing in the listener code is rendering a graph using D3 and I want to re-render that graph using the data sent each time I click the button. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are passing data="graphdata", why not data="data" ?

from my experience with Angular I found that using child variables are more effective working with directives, neither with direct variables

not:

```
$scope.data = val;
```

but:

```
$scope.state = {};

$scope.setData() = function(val) {
    $scope.state.data = val;
}
```

and pass state.data in html:

```
<div graph-visualization data="state.data" val="stability"></div>
```

you are not replacing instance of whole variable $scope.data, but just updating it properties, so watch in directive on 'data' will refer to the same instance.

You got my idea :)

Comment: The graphdata is different from the data I want to send. I just want to send it another data which has no relation to graphdata.

Comment: add more variables in directive scope and pass whatever you need

Comment: how? I can pass the variables once but how do I execute the listener code when one of them changes?

Comment: what about watching a group of variables in directive? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11952579/watch-multiple-scope-attributes