# $Watch is not working until a event is fired

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json

I am using $watch for pagination of the data in my page.But It is not showing data till i click on any of the buttons

Here is the code.

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope, $modal, Faq) {
    $scope.filteredFaqData = [];
    $scope.currentPage = 1;
    $scope.numPerPage = 5;
    $scope.maxSize = 5;
    $scope.faqData = [];
    $scope.faqData = Faq.getFaqs();
    $scope.$watch('currentPage + numPerPage', function () {
        var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage)
            , end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;
        $scope.filteredFaqData = $scope.faqData.slice(begin, end);
    });
})
```

I am getting the data in the **$scope.faqData** from the service.But the  **$scope.filteredFaqData** is empty till I click on the paging tabs

Comment: set basic value to $scope.filteredFaqData = 5 not with empty [], or ,'currentPage + numPerPage'  cant not understand, if you wanna watch more than one scope varible use watch groups http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11952579/watch-multiple-scope-attributes

Comment: @nisar It didn't make any change. Still getting the same issue

Comment: Check any error in console!!!

Comment: @nisar as you told , I used  $watchGroup in place of $watch  `$scope.$watchGroup(['currentPage','numPerPage'], function (newValues, oldValues, scope) {
            var begin = ((newValues[0] - 1) * newValues[1])
            , end = begin + newValues[1];

            $scope.filteredFaqData = $scope.faqData.slice(begin, end);
        });`

Comment: @nisar no error in the console. It is the issue of the $watch. It is not updating **$scope.filteredFaqData** when the page is loading but when i fire a even i.e when i click paging tabs it is showing data then

Comment: What is your `Faq` service using for the ajax call? If it's not $resource or $http, then use one of those. They will cause your watch to fire when the data is returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually my function **Faq.getFaqs()** was executing asynchronously . when the page loads for the first time, there was no data to display. So i used $timeout to dilay the $watch and it is working finr now.

Here is the code

```
$scope.filteredFaqData = [];
    $scope.currentPage = 1;
    $scope.numPerPage = 5;
    $scope.maxSize = 5;
    $scope.faqData = [];

        $scope.faqData = Faq.getFaqs();
        $timeout(function lateDisplay(){
            $scope.$watchGroup(['currentPage','numPerPage'], function (newValues, oldValues, scope) {
                var begin = ((newValues[0] - 1) * newValues[1])
                , end = begin + newValues[1];

                $scope.filteredFaqData = $scope.faqData.slice(begin, end);
            });
        },100);
```

Comment: Hey, great that you've found the issue. I would recommend you to not use $timeout but Promises instead. These would be ideal for your kind of situation. Read more about Promises in angular here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: @Fidel90 Does it make any difference? I mean can it cause nay problem in the program?

Comment: Well, you can't place a bet on that your http request has always finished within 100ms. As soon as your request needs a little bit longer (due to a bad connection or whatever), your $timeout executes too fast and your data isn't available. A Promise guarantees that the data is ready to be worked with. Taking a deeper look into Promises is worth the effort :)

Comment: @Fidel90 ok, Thank you for the suggestion. I will make the required changes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will do the trick:

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope, $modal, Faq) {

    //create function that can be called on several places
    var updateFilteredData = function () {
        var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage),
            end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;

        $scope.filteredFaqData = $scope.faqData.slice(begin, end);
    };

    $scope.filteredFaqData = [];
    $scope.currentPage = 1;
    $scope.numPerPage = 5;
    $scope.maxSize = 5;
    $scope.faqData = Faq.getFaqs();

    $scope.$watchGroup(['currentPage', 'numPerPage'], function () {
        //call on update
        updateFilteredData();
    });

    //initial call
    updateFilteredData();
});
```

Note: Better use `watchGroup` as it is angulars way to do what you want ([documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watchGroup)).

Comment: didn't work still page loads without any data but when i click on the paging tabs data appears.

Comment: How does your `Faq.getFaqs()` function work? Is it save that the data is available immediately? Or is it an async function that holds it result in the future. Maybe there's no result available when the filter runs initally...

Comment: I am getting the data from the service here is the code  `var self = this;
    this.faqList = [];

    $http.get('/Json/faq.json').then(function (result) {
         result.data.forEach(function (item) {
            self.addfaq(item)
        })
    });

    this.getFaqs = function () {
        return this.faqList;
    };`

Comment: I think you are right data is not availble when the page loads for the first time.So can i use timeout here to delay the call of the function

Comment: It worked thank you for pointing out the problem . I have posted the answer.