# Setup $watch on multiple scope variables in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I have two $scope variables searchList and vacancyList. The both get populated at two different instance during page load. I would like to perform certain actions once both have been loaded. How do I setup $watch on both variables?

Or if $watch is not the best option then what else I can use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Watch multiple $scope attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11952579/watch-multiple-scope-attributes)

Comment: `... once both have been loaded` what do you exactly mean by that? Could you share some codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$watch triggers directly after page load.

```
   $scope.$watch("searchList", function (newval, oldval) {

        if (newval != oldval)


            // Do somthing here
    });


      $scope.$watch("vacancyList", function (newval, oldval) {

        if (newval != oldval)


            // Do somthing here
    });
```

Comment: How Can I do the same using Collectionwatch?

Comment: $scope.$watchCollection("vacancyList", function (newval, oldval) {

        if (newval != oldval)


            // Do somthing here
    });